# creating user in Firebase using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hello I am trying to learn firebase with angularjs.

index html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<!-- Firebase Starting -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyDbul8FNC4posBAaNKhO8kiz2mdrkD539U",
        authDomain: "angularregistration-b9dec.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://angularregistration-b9dec.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "angularregistration-b9dec",
        storageBucket: "angularregistration-b9dec.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "1085945127139"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

Registration Controller

```
myApp.controller('RegistrationController',
['$scope', '$firebase', '$firebaseAuth',
    function ($scope, $firebase, $firebaseAuth) {

        var ref = firebase.database().ref();
        var auth = $firebaseAuth();

        $scope.login = function () {
            $scope.message = "Welcome " + $scope.user.email;
        };

        $scope.register = function () {

            auth.$createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                $scope.user.email,
                $scope.user.password
            ).then(function (regUser) {
                $scope.message = "Hi " + $scope.user.firstname + " thanks for registering !";

            }).catch(function (error) {
                $scope.message = error.message;
            }); //createUserWithEmailAndPassword
        }; //register
    }]); //controller
```

Registrtation Html

```
<h3 class="text-center">Register Page</h3>
<form name="myForm" novalidate ng-submit="register()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="First Name">First Name</label>
        <input ng-model="user.firstname" type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" placeholder="First name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="First Name">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" placeholder="Last name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input ng-model="user.email" type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
            placeholder="Enter email" ng-required="true">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Register</button>
</form>
<a href="#!login">Back to Login</a>

<p ng-show="message">{{message}}</p>
```

All I am trying do is trying to register user into firebase. In my index.htm I am also loading angularjs first then firebase and then follow to the angularjsfire. Every time I try to create a user it gives me error of

> {code: "auth/argument-error", message: "createUserWithEmailAndPassword failed: Second argument "password" must be a valid string."}

I tried to see another answer in stackoverflow but not able to find what I am trying to do wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated it.

Comment: If you `console.log($scope.user.password)` right before passing it into `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, what does it show?

Comment: Nothing and that was an issue. I figure it out seems like I was passing empty binding property to firebase but it did not know what the value inside the password. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After revisiting my form and reading all the binding value in the template I forgot to bind value in the password field. As soon as I was binding my password field it was working just fine.

```
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
</div>
```

Thank you @Frank van Puffelen for the quick suggestion